# ASP.NET MVC - Removing controller name from URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to remove the controller name from my URL (for one specific controller). For example:

`http://mydomain.com/MyController/MyAction`

I would want this URL to be changed to:

`http://mydomain.com/MyAction`

How would I go about doing this in MVC? I am using MVC2 if that helps me in anyway.

Comment: Check the following link will help
[How to remove the controller name from the url using rout in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650332/how-to-remove-the-controller-name-from-the-url-using-rout-in-mvc/34653793#34653793).

Comment: SEE 2016 UPDATE AT BOTTOM

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should map new route in the global.asax (add it before the default one), for example:

```
routes.MapRoute("SpecificRoute", "{action}/{id}", new {controller = "MyController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});

// default route
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} );
```

Comment: In MVC 4 I had to do this in RouteConfig.cs. Also remove the default route, its not enough to put the line before.

Comment: @David, the reason why you had to remove the default route is because your Home default index action matches `routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} );`as well. It will force the MyController Index action to render instead of your home controller Index action because your home page call qualifies for that "Route". You can replace {action} with the actual name of the method without figure braces and it will ONLY call it when you are making a call to that specific action.

Comment: See Attribute Routing answer below.

Comment: @rrejc hey there, I just did as you said but, everything works perfectly for HomeController but other controllers such as AccountController are out of reach. Could you help?

Answer (score 34):

To update this for 2016/17/18 - the best way to do this is to use Attribute Routing.

The problem with doing this in RouteConfig.cs is that the old route will also still work - so you'll have both

http://example.com/MyController/MyAction

AND

http://example.com/MyAction

Having multiple routes to the same page is bad for SEO - can cause path issues, and create zombie pages and errors throughout your app.

With attribute routing you avoid these problems and it's far easier to see what routes where. All you have to do is add this to RouteConfig.cs (probably at the top before other routes may match):

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Then add the Route Attribute to each action with the route name, eg

```
[Route("MyAction")]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
...
}
```

Comment: i Have Created in same scenario and this working also my local project but not working in my production server.

Comment: any need to route config.cs also define route or not? please suggest me.

Comment: I suggest asking a new question about this, providing proof that you've tried to trouble shoot it yourself and include code examples...

Answer (score 5):

Here is the steps for remove controller name from HomeController

**Step 1:** 
Create the route constraint.

```
public class RootRouteConstraint<T> : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var rootMethodNames = typeof(T).GetMethods().Select(x => x.Name.ToLower());
        return rootMethodNames.Contains(values["action"].ToString().ToLower());
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**
Add a new route mapping above your default mapping that uses the route constraint that we just created. The generic parameter should be the controller class you plan to use as your “Root” controller.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Root",
    "{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { isMethodInHomeController = new RootRouteConstraint<HomeController>() }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now you should be able to access your home controller methods like so: 
example.com/about, 
example.com/contact

> This will only affects HomeController. All other Controllers will have the default routing functionality.

Comment: Where is the route constraint added? RouteConfig.cs?

Comment: @NMeneses Yes, in RouteConfig.cs

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to apply to all urls/actions in the controller (https://example.com/action), you could just set the controller `Route` to empty above `ApiController`. If this controller going to be your starting controller, you'll also want to remove every `launchUrl` line in launchSettings.json.

```
[Route("")]
[ApiController]
```

Comment: that did it, simple one.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify the default routes for MVC. There is a detailed explanation at ScottGu's blog:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

The method you should change is Application_Start. Something like the following might help:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route(
  Url="MyAction"
  Defaults = { Controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" },
  RouteHandler = typeof(MvcRouteHandler)
}
```

The ordering of the routes is significant. It will stop on the first match. Thus the default one should be the last.

Answer (score -2):

```
routes.MapRoute("SpecificRoute", "MyController/{action}/{id}", 
         new {controller = "MyController", action = "Index", 
         id = UrlParameter.Optional});

// default route
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
         new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
         id = UrlParameter.Optional} );
```

Comment: `SpecificRoute` will only match if `MyController` is in the URL, the point of the question is to *exclude* the controller from the URL. See @rrejc's answer.