# correct me on url routing in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, global-asax

In my globas.asax file i have one register route

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Authentication", action = "BigClientLogin", id    = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

and in my action **"BigClientLogin"** it redirects to a new action called **"NewLogin"**. So at present my current url looks like "http://localhost:65423/Authentication/NewLogin" .But i need my url in
"http://localhost:65423/Login" format. To change action name from **"NewLogin"** to **"Login"** is not possible since i called this action many places in my solution. So is there any alternative solution for this in mvc routing? or is this is not possible and better will be to change my action name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be using the ActionName attribute. just put this on your action method

```
[ActionName("Login")]
public ActionResult NewLogin(...)
{
    ...
}
```

this would change only the Action Name, if you want only the path to be /login, use the  Route attribute:

```
[Route("login", Name = "Login")]
public ActionResult NewLogin(...)
```

Comment: That doesn't satisfy direct access using `~/Login`. This would still need to be `~/Authentication/Login`.

Comment: @BradChristie thanx, I noticed and modified the answer

Comment: Good answer assuming " i called this action many places in my solution" means "I directly call it from many places in C# code"... Renaming action will break all places where Urls are constructed via `UrlHelper.Action` (and similar) methods.

Comment: @TamimSalem thanks for your reply. I checked your solution, but Route and name not recognizing in my solution. Do i need to add any extra namespace for that?

Comment: @NithinPaul you only need System.Web.Mvc namespace.

Comment: @BradChristie Route and Name attributes not recognizing in my code.  Do i need to add anything extra to get those attributes in my code?

Comment: @NithinPaul: What version of MVC are you running? Attribute routing is new to MVC 5 (previous versions require a NuGet package).

Comment: @BradChristie My this project using mvc 3.0. May be i have to download NuGet package, thanks for pointing that.

Comment: @TamimSalem Now i got new problem i changed my route value as
routes.MapRoute(
               "Custom", // Route name
               "{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
               new { controller = "Authentication", action = "BigClientLogin", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
           );

to avoid Authentication part, But when i try to login as admin to my pages, i am getting "The resource cannot be found" because my url is http://localhost:65423/Admin/Dashboard

Comment: @BradChristie please check my above comment. Now i have this problem. So i need to alter my global.asax file?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options:

First, would be to map a route for this new login action:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "NewLogin",
  "Login",
  new { controller = "Authentication", action = "NewLogin" }
);
```

Another option, if enabled, would be to leverage Attribute routing:

```
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    [Route("~/Login", Name = "NewLogin")]
    public ActionResult NewLogin(...)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

(Just make sure `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` has been called in `RouteConfig.cs`)

With either of these, you'll have a named route you can reference in your solution (which will allow you to change it in the future if necessary):

```
@Html.RouteLink("Login", "NewLogin")
```

Comment: Now i got new problem i changed my route value as routes.MapRoute( "Default", // Route name "{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters new { controller = "Authentication", action = "BigClientLogin", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults ); to avoid Authentication part, But when i try to login as admin to my pages, i am getting "The resource cannot be found" because my url is localhost:65423/Admin/Dashboard

Answer (score 1):

You can try action aliases defined as attributes, see the article for further details:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx/

> ```
> [ActionName("View")]
> public ActionResult ViewSomething(string id) {  
>     return View();
> }
> ```
>
> The ActionNameAttribute redefines the name of this
>   action to be “View”. Thus this method is invoked in response to
>   requests for /home/view, but not for /home/viewsomething.

Comment: i tried your solution too, but my url now looks "http://localhost:65423/Authentication/Login. I don't want Authentication part in my URL. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then you need to hide controller name from the route: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337372/asp-net-mvc-removing-controller-name-from-url

Answer (score 0):

Easy - Put this before the default route above:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "BigClientLogin", // Route name
            "Login", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Authentication", action = "BigClientLogin" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```