# how to overload controllers in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to overload the MVC controllers, how can I overload it properly?

I want to list all companies in my website in a ListCompanies() controller like below

```
http://localhost:21047/Home/ListCompanies
```

and I want to add search criteria if user makes a search like below

```
http://localhost:21047/Home/ListCompanies/sera
```

"sera" is my search criteria. if search criteria exist, I want to filter my search result according to the search criteria.

here are my controllers

```
public ActionResult ListCompanies()
{
   return View(db.AY_COMPANIES);
}

[ActionName("ListCompaniesFilter")]
public ActionResult ListCompanies(string filter)
{
    var filtredCompanies = from c in db.AY_COMPANIES
                  where c.COMPANY_FULL_NAME.StartsWith(filter)
                               select c;
    return View(filtredCompanies);
}
```

and here is my ROUTING which behaves not correctly.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Home", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{filter}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "ListCompanies", filter = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

My MapRoutes are not correct because it doesnt get the search criteria properly. how can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct me on URL routing in MVC issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155168/correct-me-on-url-routing-in-mvc-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overload in this manner because there is dispatch issue due to two routes on having the same three parts, they are essentially the same.

```
"{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

and

```
"{controller}/{action}/{filter}"
```

One way is to collapse the two action methods into one

```
public ActionResult ListCompanies(string filter)
```

then if filter is null return the full list else return the filtered list. 
I am not fond of this approach.

A better yet simple way to fix this is:

1) remove the second route (the one with the filter)

2) change the signature of the action method from

```
public ActionResult ListCompanies(string filter)
```

to

```
public ActionResult ListCompanies(string id)
```

allowing the first route to match the parameter on name.

3) Since you can't overload methods you'll need to use your ActionName when requesting the filtered result,

```
 http://localhost:21047/Home/ListCompaniesFilter/sera
```

Answer (score 2):

First these routes are exactly the same:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",
              id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Home", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{filter}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "ListCompanies", 
              filter = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
    );
```

They are exactly the same because the number of parameters exactly match (what you name parameters nor the parameter type does not change the *signature* of the http request method).

There are few different ways to make this work.  You could write a [MapRoute Constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) for Default that would prevent it from working if the controller/action/id matched a specific set of criteria.  Probably not the best course of action.

Since

> http://localhost:21047/Home/ListCompanies
>   http://localhost:21047/Home/ListCompanies/sera
>   http://localhost:21047/Home/ListCompanies/text
>   http://localhost:21047/Home/ListCompanies/search

are programmatically the same request with `{id}` having a null value for your method `ListCompanies()` I would probably write it like:

```
public ActionResult ListCompanies(string id)
{
  var query = db.AY_COMPANIES;

  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
  {
    query.Where(c => c.COMPANY_FULL_NAME.StartsWith(id))
  }

  var model = query.ToList();

  return View(model);
}
```

And remove your "Home" MapRoute, it won't be needed.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you have only one action with an optional parameter? Something like as the following:

```
public ActionResult ListCompanies(string filter = null)
{
    var filteredCompanies = string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter)
         ? db.AY_COMPANIES
         : from c in db.AY_COMPANIES
           where c.COMPANY_FULL_NAME.StartsWith(filter)
           select c;
    return View(filteredCompanies);
}
```

Comment: `filter` will always be null unless the correct MapRoute is used.