# If Route doesn't exist -> go to other route using its default action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

So I'm having a little problem here with routing.

There are two parts to this web application:
  1. Brochure / Display Website
  2. Internal Site / Client Application

We wanted a way to release changes for the brochure without having to do a whole release of said *Web* application.
Visiting existing named views will take the user to a brochure page, however if it doesn't exist, it will act like they are a *client* and will redirect them to their company's login screen.

Global.asax:

```
//if view doesnt exist then url is a client and should be redirected
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Brochure",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "brochure", action = "Brochure", id = "Index" },
    namespaces: new[] { "Web.Areas.Brochure.Controllers" }
);

//This is home page
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HomeDefault",
    url: "{client}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index" },
    namespaces: new string[] { "Web.Controllers" }
);
```

Controller:

```
/// <summary> Check if the view exists in our brochure list </summary>
private bool ViewExists(string name) {
    ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, name, null);
    return (result.View != null);
}

/// <summary> Generic action result routing for all pages. 
/// If the view doesn't exist in the brochure area, then redirect to interal web
/// This way, even when we add new pages to the brochure, there is no need to re-compile & release the whole Web project. </summary>
public ActionResult Brochure(string id) {
    if (ViewExists(id)) {
        return View(id);
    }

    return RedirectToRoute("HomeDefault", new { client = id });
}
```

This code works fine up until we log in and go to the landing page. It seems to keep the **Brochure** action in the route and doesn't want to go to the subsequent controller which results in a 500 error.
e.g. 'domain/client/Brochure' when it *needs* to be: 'domain/client/Index'

**Things tried but not worked**:

- Changing `RedirectToRoute()` to a `RedirectToAction()` - this results in a
  finite loop of going back to the `ActionResult Brochure()`. So
  changing controllers through that didn't work.
- Create an ActionResult called `Brochure()` inside the 'HomeController'. It
  doesn't even get hit.
- Passed in `namespaces` for `RedirectToRoute()` as an attribute. I knew this would probably not work, but it was worth a try.

---

**So the question is:**
How can I get the route to act properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can restrict `id` to some subset of all values you can add that [constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route.constraints%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to route (i.e. numbers only) to let default handle the rest.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Brochure",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "brochure", action = "Brochure", id = "Index" },
    namespaces: new[] { "Web.Areas.Brochure.Controllers" }
    constraints : new { category = @"\d+"}
);
```

If you can't statically determine restrictions - automatically redirecting in your `BrochureController` similar to your current code would work. The only problem with sample in the question is it hits the same route again and goes into infinite redirect loop - redirect to Url that does not match first rule:

```
// may need to remove defaults from second route 
return RedirectToRoute("HomeDefault", new { client = id, action = "index" });
```

If standard constraints do not work and you must keep single segment in url - use custom constraints - implement `IRouteConstraint` and use it in first route. See [Creating custom constraints](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs).

Comment: A good reply, however both are just text. So unfortunately this wont work :(

Comment: @ChiMo I've added one more way.

Comment: Thanks Alexei, Custom constraints seem very handy! Not entirely sure how this would affect page load time though.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I could have solved this issue:

### Way 1

I reviewed the redirect and just passed in an action in order to get a route that has 2 segments in the url. i.e. *client/Index*. The *Index* action now handles logins - going past a custom controller.
`public class HomeController : CustomController`

```
public ActionResult Brochure(string id, string action) {
    if (ViewExists(id)) {
        return View(id);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { client = id, action = "Index" });
}
```

### Way 2

(from @Alexei_Levenkov)
Create a custom Route constraint so the route will be ignored if the view cannot be found.

```
namespace Web.Contraints {
    public class BrochureConstraint : IRouteConstraint {
        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection) {
            //Create our 'fake' controllerContext as we cannot access ControllerContext here
            HttpContextWrapper context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
            RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "brochure");
            ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(new RequestContext(context, routeData), new BrochureController());

            //Check if our view exists in the folder -> if so the route is valid - return true
            ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controllerContext, "~/Areas/Brochure/Views/Brochure/" + values["id"] + ".cshtml", null);
            return result.View != null;
        }
    }
}

namespace Web {
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
        //If view doesnt exist then url is a client so use the 'HomeDefault' route below
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Brochure",
            url: "{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "brochure", action = "Brochure", id = "Index" },
            namespaces: new[] { "Web.Areas.Brochure.Controllers" },
            constraints: new { isBrochure = new BrochureConstraint() }
        );

        //This is home page for client
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "HomeDefault",
            url: "{client}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index" },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Web.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your configuration. I can explain what is wrong with it, but I am not sure I can set you on the right track because you didn't provide the all of the URLs (at least not all of them from what I can tell).

### Issues

1. Your `Brouchure` route, which has 1 *optional* URL segment named `{id}`, will match *any* URL that is 0 or 1 segments (such as `/` and `/client`). The fact that it matches your home page (and you have another route that is named `HomeDefault` that will never be given the chance to match the home page) leads me to believe this wasn't intended. You can make the `{id}` value required by removing the default value `id = "Index"`.
2. The `Brouchure` route has a namespace that indicates it is probably in an `Area`. To properly register the area, you have to make the last line of that route `).DataTokens["area"] = "Brochure";` or alternatively put it into the `/Areas/Brouchure/AreaRegistration.cs` file, which will do that for you.
3. The only way to get to the `HomeDefault` route is to supply a 2 segment URL (such as `/client/Index`, which will take you to the `Index` method on the `HomeController`). The example URLs you have provided have 3 segments. Neither of the routes you have provided will match a URL with 3 segments, so if these URLs are not getting 404 errors they are obviously matching a route that you haven't provided in your question. In other words, you are looking for the problem in the wrong place.

If you provide your *entire* route configuration including all Area routes and AttributeRouting routes (including the line that registers them), as well as a *complete* description of what URL should go to what action method, I am sure you will get more helpful answers.

> **So the question is:**
>   How can I get the route to act properly?

Unknown. Until you describe what *properly* is.

Related: [Why map special routes first before common routes in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661062/why-map-special-routes-first-before-common-routes-in-asp-net-mvc/35674633#35674633)

Comment: That is the whole point. 'HomeDefault is my 2 segmented' url and everything else has 3 segments (not relevant to the issue)

Comment: `HomeDefault` will match *only* URLs that are 2 segments. The `Brouchure` route matches every URL that is 1 segment, so none of those URLs are given a chance to match the `HomeDefault` route. You have not posted any routes that will match the 3 segment URLs you have posted. The behavior you are experiencing is likely coming from matching routes you have not posted.

Comment: I have solved the issue @NightOwl888, thanks for your input. My 3+ segmented urls have nothing to do with the current issue so I did not provide them.