# Set a route to an area without specifying the area name in the url in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an `MVC 4` application. In that application I have certain Areas, whose URL is not resolved properly. The `LocationAreaRegistration.cs` is as follows:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Location_default",
            "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { culture = "en", action = "LocationIndex", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { controller = "(LocationIndex)" }
        );
```

My `route.config` is as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Default",
                 url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                 defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                 namespaces: new[] { "Locator.Areas.Location.Controllers" }
               ).DataTokens.Add("area", "Location");
```

I have also tried to change the `route.config` as below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Default",
             url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             namespaces: new[] { "Locator.Areas.Location.Controllers" }
           );
```

None of the approaches worked and I get `The resource cannot be found` error.

However when I change the `LocationAreaRegistration.cs` as follows, it works:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Location_default",
            "{culture}/Location/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { culture = "en", action = "LocationIndex", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { controller = "(LocationIndex)" }
        );
```

But I do not want the URL to contain the `Location`(Area name). What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

The URLs that I would be going to will be somewhat like:

```
http://localhost/en/LocationIndex/LocationIndex
```

Here `en` is the current culture, `Home` is the `controller` name and `Index` is the `action method` name.

Comment: Good set of MapRoutes, but without knowing the URLs your going to, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: I have edited my question. Please check

Comment: Your routing is misconfigured. See [Why map special routes first before common routes in asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661062/why-map-special-routes-first-before-common-routes-in-asp-net-mvc/35674633).

Comment: @NightOwl888- Yes this will be the case if I redirect to `http://localhost/en/Home/Index`. What if I redirect to `http://localhost/en/LocationIndex/LocationIndex`, then it should get redirected to the LocationIndex action of LocationIndex controller in the area Location, but it is not redirecting. P.S. - Updated my URL in the question

Comment: @Alorika - If using the built-in routing, the URL must contain *something* that routing can identify as the area for the area route to match. That something could be a literal segment or a route constraint (which could use Reflection to only match areas that exist). You said you don't want to use a literal segment, but it is unclear why that is unacceptable. Are you trying to put your default site functionality into the Location area?

Comment: @NightOwl888-Yes I will be putting the default site functionality into the Location area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the `Location` area the default set of routes for your MVC application, you just need to define your `RouteConfig.cs` as follows:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default_Localized",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { culture = new CultureConstraint(defaultCulture: "en", pattern: "[a-z]{2}") },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Locator.Areas.Location.Controllers" }
        ).DataTokens["area"] = "Location";

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Locator.Areas.Location.Controllers" }
        ).DataTokens["area"] = "Location";
    }
}
```

Note that this will completely *replace* any functionality of your default controllers in the application and send all of the requests to the `Location` namespace.

You should *not* put any route definitions into your `LocationAreaRegistration.cs` file. This will ensure they are run *last* and don't screw with any of your other area routes.

Here is the definition of `CultureConstraint`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32839796/181087) for more details about how to localize your routes.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

public class CultureConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly string defaultCulture;
    private readonly string pattern;

    public CultureConstraint(string defaultCulture, string pattern)
    {
        this.defaultCulture = defaultCulture;
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public bool Match(
        HttpContextBase httpContext, 
        Route route, 
        string parameterName, 
        RouteValueDictionary values, 
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.UrlGeneration && 
            this.defaultCulture.Equals(values[parameterName]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return Regex.IsMatch((string)values[parameterName], "^" + pattern + "$");
        }
    }
}
```