# Asp.net MVC 5 MapRoute for multiple routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute

I have 3 routes in RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ByGroupName",
    url: "catalog/{categoryname}/{groupname}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Catalog" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ByCatName",
    url: "catalog/{categoryname}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Catalog" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ByBrandId",
    url: "catalog/brand/{brandId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Catalog" }
);
```

and this is my action controller receiving parameters:

```
public ActionResult Catalog(
    string categoryName = null,
    string groupName = null,
    int pageNumber = 1,
    int orderBy = 5,
    int pageSize = 20,
    int brandId = 0,
    bool bundle = false,
    bool outlet = false,
    string query_r = null)
{
// ...
}
```

when I Use in view a link with `@Url.RouteUrl("ByBrandId", new {brandId = 5})`, I get in Action a parameter "categoryname"="brand" and brandId=0 instead of only brandId=5...

When I Call `"http://localhost:3453/catalog/brand/5"` with "ByBrandId" routeurl I want to get brandId=5 in actioncontroller..., the equivalent of `"http://localhost:3453/catalog/Catalog?brandId=1"`

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your routing is misconfigured. If you pass the URL `/Catalog/brand/something` it will *always* match the `ByGroupName` route instead of the intended `ByBrandId` route.

First of all, you should correct the order. But also, the first 2 routes are exactly the same except for the optional group name, so you can simplify to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ByBrandId",
    url: "catalog/brand/{brandId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Catalog" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ByGroupName",
    url: "catalog/{categoryname}/{groupname}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Catalog", groupname = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now when you use `@Url.RouteUrl("ByBrandId", new {brandId = 5})` it should give you the expected output `/catalog/brand/5`.

See [Why map special routes first before common routes in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674633/181087) for a complete explanation.