# Asp.net MVC route config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, routeconfig

First, I'm not a developer (ui designer), but I'm having to work with some asp.net, well, because life...so I know little to nothing.

I have a structure like this:

**Views > Partners >**

and inside the "Partners", I have over 40 files named in CamelCase, like FileName.cshtml etc...

I need to re-route the url so instead of "**website/Partners/PartnerName**", it would be like this "**website/partners/partner-name**"

I tried tons of tutorials, but I just cannot understand what needs to be done to achieve this.
The closest I got to a solution, was using the "**[Route("partners/partner-name")]**" inside the Partners controller. But for this solution, I have to add that line of code to all of the 40 files (gonna have more than a hundred in the future). I believe there must be some way to automatically do it for all the pages I have, instead of manually editing each one of them.

Again, I'm not a developer, I'm just having to deal with this right now, and I know almost nothing about .net. Thanks.

Comment: Which asp.net mvc version are you using?

Comment: 4.6.1 I believe

Answer (score 0):

I guess 4.6.1 is the .Net-Framework. So I just shoot an answer which applies to MVC 5 and we see how good it fits for you. (Because Versioning is tricky - confusing lately in the dotnet space).

You can override routing in a file called `RouteConfig.cs`

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "OverrideRoute",
            url: "websites/partners/{partner-name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "AnController", action ="AnAction" }
    );
```

Beware the order matters first-match wins. Also this is set up do act like `/websites/partners/contosocompany` if you want especially `websites/partners/partner-name/contosocompany` (<- less nice and readable) you would need to adjust the `url` property in `MapRoute`

It should also be possible to group routes see this answer here: [Asp.net MVC 5 MapRoute for multiple routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969797/asp-net-mvc-5-maproute-for-multiple-routes)

And please talk to your developers if you have certain sections which are almost like individual mvc pages you could also take advantage of a concept called `areas`. For example your partners section could be an area.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0

... and keep in mind if you are a designer who can look into code, read and change it - you got already a business advantage in our industry.