# Why does the "Default" site route to the site root in ASP.NET MVC work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

ASP.NET MVC sites come with the following default root that executes the Index action of the Home controller when the root of the site is visited (e.g. `http://localhost:12345`)

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

So it's a kind of fallback when no route is found then?

Not so fast. If we try and navigate to `http://localhost/a/b` (where no 'a' controller exists) it will not execute the Index action of the Home controller - an error will be returned.

Why does that fail to execute Home/Index in that scenario - but entering absolutely nothing in the path does execute Home/Index?

What is the logic here - and why is this route called 'defaults'?

I've seen a lot of articles cover routing - but not one where this is explained.

**Related Question**

In other situations what is in 'defaults' seems more like a mapping of a route. For example

```
url: "abc/def", defaults: new { controller = "bongo", action = "bingo" }
```

This just executes the bingo action on the bongo controller - whenever the exact url "abc/def" is entered. Why is it called 'defaults' - that term doesn't seem to fit really. (does removing 'defaults' have any effect, I have seen it omitted).

In the Default route it seems more like a fallback, in the latter example more like a mapping?

I feel like there is something at the conceptual level I am missing here.

thx.

Comment: Note - I have switched to using Attribute Routing instead - WAY WAY easier to get your head round and WAY less potential for accidental or broken routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic, while not very intuitive at first, is actually pretty simple.

In general, there are 2 different things going on when an incoming request happens.

1. Attempt to match the route
2. Supply MVC with a set of route values (and optionally, route metadata), which it uses to lookup the action method

When an incoming request happens, MVC executes the `GetRouteData` method of the first route in the route table. If it doesn't match, it will attempt the second, third, and so on until a match is found.

If ultimately there is no match in the route table, `RouteCollection.GetRouteData` (the method that calls `GetRouteData` of each route) will return `null`. If a match is found, the route values from the matching route will be returned to MVC where it uses them to lookup the controller and action to execute. Do note that in this case *no other routes in the route table are checked* for a match. In other words, the first match always wins.

The matching process relies on 3 things:

1. Placeholders
2. Literal segments
3. Constraints

## Placeholders

The part you are asking about are *placeholders* and why they match when no value is present. Placeholders (i.e. `{controller}`) act like variables. They will accept any value. They can be *initialized to a default value*. If they are not initialized to a default value, they are *required to be in the URL* in order to match.

Consider the `defaults` in the route definition:

```
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

These are the values that will be used (as both the match and the output in the RouteValues) if the *placeholder is not supplied in the URL*.

By this same logic, by default all of these URLs will reach the `HomeController.Index` action method.

- `/`
- `/Home`
- `/Home/Index`
- `/Home/Index/Foo`
- `/Home/Index/123`

> URL: `/`

If you pass the URL `/` to the framework, it will match the `Default` route *and send it to the `HomeController.Index` method* because the default values are `Home` and `Index` if none are supplied. In this case, the route values are:

```
| Key         | Value       |
|-------------|-------------|
| controller  | Home        |
| action      | Index       |
| id          | {}          |
```

> URL `/Home`

Note that you could also just pass the controller name `/Home`. The route table looks exactly the same.

```
| Key         | Value       |
|-------------|-------------|
| controller  | Home        |
| action      | Index       |
| id          | {}          |
```

However, in this case the `controller` value is being passed in through the placeholder in the URL. It is not considering the default `controller` value of the route anymore because a value has been supplied in the URL.

> URL: `/Test`

Following this same logic, the URL `/Test` will result in the following route table.

```
| Key         | Value       |
|-------------|-------------|
| controller  | Test        |
| action      | Index       |
| id          | {}          |
```

Routing doesn't check automatically whether the controller actually exists. It just supplies the values. If there is no controller in your application named `TestController` with an `Index` action, this will result in an error.

This is why the URL `/a/b` you supplied above doesn't work - there is no controller in your project named `AController` with an action named `B`.

> If placeholders are not initialized to a default value, they are *required to be in the URL* in order for the route to match.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So, given the above route, it will match the URL `/Home`:

```
| Key         | Value       |
|-------------|-------------|
| controller  | Home        |
| action      | Index       |
| id          | {}          |
```

But it won't match the URL `/` because there is no default value for controller.

## Literal Segments

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Foo",
    url: "abc/def",
    defaults: new { controller = "bongo", action = "bingo" }
);
```

The above route uses *literal segments* in the URL. Literal segments require an exact match (case insensitive) in order for the route to be considered a match. Therefore, the only URL that matches is `abc/def` or any uppercase/lowercase combination of these 2 segments.

However, this scenario differs in one regard. There is *no way to pass a value through the URL*. Therefore you *must* set default values (at the very least for `controller` and `action`) in order for any route values to be passed on to MVC.

```
| Key         | Value       |
|-------------|-------------|
| controller  | bongo       |
| action      | bingo       |
```

The MVC framework requires there to be a `BongoController` with an action named `Bingo` or this route will fail miserably.

## Constraints

Constraints are *extra criteria* that is required in order for the route to match. Each constraint returns a boolean (match/no match) response. You can have 0 to many constraints per route.

### [RegEx constraints](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CustomRoute",
    url: "{placeholder1}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyController" },
    constraints: new { placeholder1 = @"^house$|^car$|^bus$" }
);
```

Matches

- `/house/details/123`
- `/car/foo/bar`
- `/car/bar/foo`

Doesn't Match

- `/house/details`
- `/bank/details/123`
- `/bus/foo`
- `/car`
- `/`

### [Custom constraints](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs)

```
public class CorrectDateConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var year = values["year"] as string;
        var month = values["month"] as string;
        var day = values["day"] as string;

        DateTime theDate;
        return DateTime.TryParse(year + "-" + month + "-" + day, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out theDate);
    }
}

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CustomRoute",
    url: "{year}/{month}/{day}/{article}",
    defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "ArticleDetails" },
    constraints: new { year = new CorrectDateConstraint() }
);
```

**Note:** The value that the constraint is assigned to (in the above case `year =`) is the same value that is passed into the custom constraint. However, the custom constraint has no obligation to use this value. Sometimes it doesn't make sense to use any value, in which case you can set the constraint on `controller`.

Matches

- `/2012/06/20/some-great-article`
- `/2016/12/25/all-about-christmas`

Doesn't Match

- `/2012/06/33/some-great-article`
- `/2012/06/20`
- `/99999/09/09/the-foo-article`

In most cases, you *should use constraints* whenever there are placeholders (such as `{controller}` or `{something}`) in the URL to keep them from matching values that they shouldn't.

> Literal segments (or partial literal segments with placeholders), constraints, and required values are all generally *very good* things to use in your routing setup. They help to ensure that your routes don't match in such a wide scope that they block execution of routes registered after them in the route table.
>
> Placeholders match *any value*, so it is generally not recommended to use only placeholders in any route but the `Default` route unless done in conjunction with constraints. Many folks here on StackOverflow recommend to *remove the `Default` route entirely* to ensure that unintended routes don't function, and I don't necessarily disagree with this sentiment.

## Further Reading

- [ASP.NET Routing (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)
- [Why map special routes first before common routes in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674633/181087)

Comment: Thanks. 'defaults' still seems to fulfil 2 totally disparate roles. Your 'no values provided so use the default values for controller and action' makes sense. But where the segments are literal (or mixed, e.g. "myplace/{URL}" - you always use the 'defaults' controller & action. I get this is how it works - but it just seems like a separate concept - and the phrase 'defaults' no longer seems appropriate? "mapping" seems like a better word. Maybe I just have to live with this?

Comment: Perhaps it is better if you think of them as 'initial values' than 'defaults'. And to think of placeholders as 'variables' and literal segments as 'constants', both which can have 'initial values'. This is more analogous to the way variables and constants work in a programming language. When you leave the 'initial value' out of the setup, you must set it in the program (the URL), but this is not possible with a constant as it is with a variable. It is also possible to overwrite an initial variable value, but not a constant value.