# Is it possible to remove [webmethod] actual path from $.ajax url asp.net webform

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have created a webpage whose path is: `https://localhost:44313/Pages/Services/reissue_ticket.aspx` and I routed the page in global.asax like: `route.MapPageRoute("Reissue", "reissue","~/Pages/Services/reissue_ticket.aspx");` So now the page url is : `https://localhost:44313/reissue` which has [WebMethod] called GetAirlines().

in script I use $.ajax to call the function. ajax is below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Pages/Services/reissue_ticket.aspx/GetAirlines",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#result").html(response.d);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert("Failed to call GetInfo web method.");
    }
});
```

Is there any way to call method from backend with ajax url only using `url: "/GetAirlines"`

Thanks in advance.

I tried so hard to solve this problem but can't. Even I tried to create a webservices.asxh and rewrite into web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="RewriteToWebService_GetAirlines" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^GetAirlines$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="WebServices.asmx/GetAirlines" />
      </rule>
      
      
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: You have a route "GetAirlines" and a method called "GetAirlines()".  So simply add a Route to your controller which has one instruction "GetAirlines();"  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289366/c-sharp-mvc-routing-and-ajax-calls

Comment: Thanks jdweng. I don't know how to use controller in asp net webform

Comment: Shouldn't your .asxh webhandler go to the code behind method (like the ajax `url`), not the .asmx web service?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. I solved this with asp.net Web API. I didn't know about Web API before. It works as expected.