# Id coming Null in the Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controllers

Don't know why, but my Action method showing null for id. I'm passing id in the url but still its coming null

### Controller Action Method

```
public ActionResult SpecificEmpDetails(string empId)
{
    CustomerBAL customer = new CustomerBAL();
    Customer custs = customer.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmpID.ToString() == empId);
    ViewBag.Customers = custs;
    return View("EmpDetails");
}
```

### View

```
   <ul>
            <li>
                Customer ID : @ViewBag.Customers.EmpID
            </li>
            <li>
                Customer Name : @ViewBag.Customers.EmpName
            </li>
            <li>
                Customer Age : @ViewBag.Customers.EmpAge
            </li>
            <li>
                Customer Gender : @ViewBag.Customers.EmpGender
            </li>
            <li>
                Customer Salary : @ViewBag.Customers.EmpSalary
            </li>
        </ul>
```

### Employee Database Context

```
public class CustomerBAL : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

### Employee Model Class

```
[Table("tblEmployee")]
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public string EmpGender { get; set; }
    public int EmpAge { get; set; }
    public int EmpSalary { get; set; }
}
```

### Route Config

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "SpecificUser",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "SpecificEmpDetails", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

### URL

localhost:8983/Test/SpecificEmpDetails/1

Id is coming as null, but when I'm changing the ID(in the watch window) during debugging from null to any available id, its showing the required employee data. I'm totally confused why id is not getting passed to the controller action method from the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 different things going on here.

### Routing

First of all, your route definition is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "SpecificUser",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "SpecificEmpDetails", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

You are specifying that the name of the *route value* that is passed is `{id}`. Therefore, any URL that matches this route will be entered into the URL table with the route key of `id` and value that is passed in the URL.

For example, with the URL `/Test/SpecificEmpDetails/1`, your route table looks like this:

```
| Key         | Value               |
|-------------|---------------------|
| controller  | Test                |
| action      | SpecificEmpDetails  |
| id          | 1                   |
```

The reason it looks this way is because you are passing the values in the URL, and they are being converted into route values via the placeholders you defined.

### Value Providers

The way MVC gets the values to the action method parameters (or technically, any value of a Model) is through *value providers*.

Value providers lookup the key from several places, such as query string parameters, form values, and route values to try to match the *key names* with what are in each of those dictionaries. If the *parameter name* of the action method matches, it will pass the value through. If there is no match, the value will be the default value of the data type.

You can see the value providers that are registered by default (and what order of precedence they have) by looking at the static `ValueProviderFactories.Factories` property. You can also remove and add/insert custom value provider factories to this property.

[image]

Therefore, with a [custom value provider](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/smart-working-with-custom-value-providers-in-Asp-Net-mvc/), you *could* make one name map to another name if you really wanted to. In this case, you could make the request for the key `empId` match the route value `id`.

That said, I recommend you do one of the following.

### Option 1: Use the Default Route, and stick with the name "Id"

The route you have provided won't work in the same MVC application as the default route. The reason is that it will match *any* URL that has 0, 1, 2, or 3 segments *just like the default route*. If a URL of this length is passed to the application, it will match the first route registered and will ignore the other. See [Why map special routes first before common routes in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674633/181087) for a complete explanation.

So, if you just use one route in your application, and use `id` as both your route key and action method parameter, everything will flow accordingly and will be *simpler* than using a custom route.

IMO, it probably doesn't make much sense to make the `id` parameter optional for this particular URL. You have no code in your action method to deal with an empty `id` value anyway. Note however if you pass the URL `/Test/SpecificEmpDetails`, it will still match the `Default` route and match your controller action anyway (with an empty value). To avoid this, you can insert an `IgnoreRoute` to block the URL from matching in this case.

```
// Ignore the URL if it is passed with no id, so you get a 404 not found
routes.IgnoreRoute("Test/SpecificEmpDetails");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And your action method:

```
public ActionResult SpecificEmpDetails(string id)
{
    CustomerBAL customer = new CustomerBAL();
    Customer custs = customer.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmpID.ToString() == id);
    ViewBag.Customers = custs;
    return View("EmpDetails");
}
```

### Option 2: Use a custom route and change the parameter name to "empId"

If you want a custom route, you must *constrain* the route so it will not match *every* value that is passed. In this case, you only want it to match `/Test/SpecificEmpDetails/<SomeID>`, so the simplest option is just to use literal segments instead of placeholders.

You also need to [place your custom route first before the default route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674633/181087) or it will be an unreachable execution path.

As above, it will still match the `Default` route and match your controller action anyway (with a `null` value, since `id` is not equal to `empId`). So you should also insert an `IgnoreRoute` to block the URL from matching in this case.

```
// Ignore the URL if it is passed with no empId, so you get a 404 not found
routes.IgnoreRoute("Test/SpecificEmpDetails");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SpecificUser",
    url: "Test/SpecificEmpDetails/{empId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "SpecificEmpDetails" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then you can use your method as you have it in your question.

```
public ActionResult SpecificEmpDetails(string empId)
{
    CustomerBAL customer = new CustomerBAL();
    Customer custs = customer.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmpID.ToString() == empId);
    ViewBag.Customers = custs;
    return View("EmpDetails");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton man....finally what I was looking for and thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The `Id` in Url will not pass into `empId` becasuse in the MapRoute the number after action will goes to `Id` not `empId`

Change your action like this and everything will works fine.

```
public ActionResult SpecificEmpDetails(string Id)
{
    CustomerBAL customer = new CustomerBAL();
    Customer custs = customer.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmpID.ToString() == Id);
    ViewBag.Customers = custs;
    return View("EmpDetails");
}
```

If you don't want to change your method, you must use this url in order to fix it :

```
localhost:8983/Test/SpecificEmpDetails?empId=1
```

Comment: Wow, excellent its working, But how does changing empId to Id make any difference

Comment: Do we always have to write it as Id only not any other name in the action method.

Comment: @BhuwanPandey It's all about MapRoute. in MapRoute in url you have "{controller}/{action}/{id}", which means first word is controller, second one is action and the third one will assign to a input named Id

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
               name: "SpecificUser",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "SpecificEmpDetails", EmpId = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );  Can I write EmpId here instead of id...and EmpId in the action method also, will that work

Comment: One thing I noticed doesn't matter what I name it in route config, it is only working when I name it id in the Controller action method... Is this how it works???

Comment: You  forgot to change the url of MapRoute.   routes.MapRoute( name: "SpecificUser", url: "{controller}/{action}/{EmpId}", defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "SpecificEmpDetails", EmpId = UrlParameter.Optional } )

Comment: I did that, but with that change its throwing runtime error and id coming null