# Weird routing behavior in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, html-helper

Consider the following sidebar:

[image]

If I press the sub menu item `All solutions` under the menu item `Solutions`, I would see a grid somewhat like this one:

[image]

The url for this grid is `https://something.com/Solutions`. Now imagine that I wanted to go into the menu item `Partners` and sub menu item `Active`, the url would be `https://something.com/Partners/active`.

I'm using a simple `Html.ActionLink` like so:

```
Html.ActionLink("- Active", "Active", "Partners", null, new { @class = "filter-button" })
```

**PROBLEM**

Navigating the user to the url `https://something.com/Partners/active` using the `Html.ActionLink` the way I do, this should work, but it doesn't. Instead of redirecting me to the active partners view, the application redirects me back to `https://something.com/Solutions` (*exactly where I came from*) but with this url: `https://something.com/Solutions?undefined=undefined`.

If I press the `Active`sub menu item in the menu item `Partners` once more, the url hanges to `https://something.com/Solutions?undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined` and this goes on forever.

I have no idea why this occurs nor do I have any solution.

**PARTNERS/ACTIVE**

```
public ActionResult Active()
{
    using(var db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        var partners = db.Partners.Where(x => x.Active).ToList();

        return View(partners);
    }
}
```

**ROUTE DEFINITIONS**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ControllerIdActionId",
    url: "{controller}/{id}/{action}/{id2}",
    defaults: new { id2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Solutions",
    url: "{controller}/{id}/{action}/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

**UPDATE**

After reviewing the route definitions, I noticed that the route definition `Solutions` was never used. I've now removed that route definition so the route definitions look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ControllerIdActionId",
    url: "{controller}/{id}/{action}/{id2}",
    defaults: new { id2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This had made no difference though. I tried changing the two routes around so the `ControllerIdActionId` route would be registered before the `Default`, but this has no effect either.

Comment: Can you post this action `/Partners/active`

Comment: Show your route definitions as well

Comment: Both have been added.

Comment: Your routes are out of order (and they do not make sense). Temporarily comment out both the `ControllerIdActionId` and `Solutions` routes and check it

Comment: @StephenMuecke how did you find out the "routes are out of order"?

Comment: @StephenMuecke That could prove a challenge as I'm using the route definition `Solutions` in my grid. If this is the problem, are their other ways I can test it, perhaps even a possible solution?

Comment: @Alex,They make no sense :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke how to make routes to make sense, if I have multiple routes, does it matter the order in which they are coded?

Comment: @Detilium, You need to explain what you trying to achieve with those routes. They simply cannot work correctly as you have shown them. If you want the `Active()` method of `SolutionsController` to generate `.../Solutions`, then you need a specific route - `routes.MapRoute( name: "Solutions", url "Solutions", defaults: new { controller = "Solutions", action = "Active } }` and it needs to be the first one

Comment: @StephenMuecke I haven't really looked into the route definitions as I didn't create them in the first place. I'll take a look at them and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: @StephenMuecke No wait, I think you misunderstood my structure, or I wrote it wrong at least. The method I'm hitting in not `Active()` but `Index()` as the sub menu item hit is called `All solutions` and not `Active`. This is a typo from my part. Will update the post.

Comment: I think you need to do some research on routing in MVC :). I don't want to write a book chapter, but your first route means - match anything with 3 or 4 segments in it - so (say) `../Product/Edit/1` would match it because it contains 3 segments (and its the first route). As it is, the other 2 routes are a bit pointless because it will never get that far.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Except, with `RouteLink()`'s I'm capable of telling MVC what route definition to use. I suppose this was the main idea behind it.

Comment: You still need to place your routes in order (most specific first) - a user can type a url in the address bar :)

Comment: `ControllerIdActionId` should take place on top of `Default` one. The MVC routing system is top-down processing model, most specific routes should defined first.

Comment: See [Why map special routes first before common routes in asp.net mvc?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35674633/181087). Both of your routes have much overlap on which URLs they match, but the first match always wins so you are sure to get unexpected behavior with this configuration. Placeholders can contain *any value*, they are given a name, but that doesn't mean routing will understand what they are for. See my link for some possible solutions.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I can see what you mean, but I'm just not sure what the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the routes is important. Please change the order of the routes. Move the `Default` route to 1st position and try.

Also the routes `ControllerIdActionId` and `Solutions` needs to be refined, they look out of order. Please try to follow certain pattern to avoid complications.

E.g. `Controller/Action/ID`