# RedirectToRoute redirects to the current action instead of redirecting to the route specified by the routename

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, redirecttoroute

Below is my `RouteConfig.cs` code snippet:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "myroute",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and in `Home/Contact` I am redirecting to the route named "myroute", which maps to `Home/About`. Instead of redirecting to `Home/About`, it is redirecting to the same action (`Home/Contact`). Below is my `HomeController` code:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return RedirectToRoute("myroute");
    }
```

Why is the redirect to `myroute` not functioning?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have not specified the action name so it uses the values from the current request - you need `return RedirectToRoute("myroute", new { action = "About" });` or make the route specific if you want it to go to `About`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `RedirectToRoute`, `Html.RouteLink`, `Url.RouteUrl`, and related methods that allow you to specify a route by name, the name acts like an additional filter. Basically, it means the route *can* only match the route named `"myroute"`, but you still need to provide `controller`, `action`, and any other required route values in order to match that route.

```
RedirectToRoute("myroute", new { controller = "Home", action = "About" })
```

Note that @StephenMuecke 's answer provided in a comment will also work, but only from the `Home` controller. MVC automatically reuses values from the current request when generating URLs if not explicitly provided.

> On a side note, this routing configuration is fundamentally broken because you have 2 routes that both accept lengths of 0, 1, 2, and 3 route segments. Basically, while it is possible to generate a URL with `myroute`, no incoming route can match `myroute` because `Default` is configured to always override it. This will likely lead to problems because the route you *intended* for that path is never matched, which is going to be confusing to maintain when you add more routes.
>
> See [Why map special routes first before common routes in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674633/181087) for the specifics of this problem and possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it easier. Use Response.Redirect("Home/About") But I don't know if there are any other requirements.