# ASP.NET Core 2 default route having areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-routing

cI went through various posts regarding the Areas routing but still I am not able to resolve my issue.

I would like to split my application in the way that there are two routes.

- `/Areas/Panel`
- `/Areas/Website`

Inside each area there is `HomeController` and appropriate methods that correspond to actions.

I would like that whenever user lands to any level 1 route i.e.:

- /home
- /contact
- /about/company
- etc.

is directed to `/Areas/Website/{controller}/{action}`

and alternatively for

- /panel
- /panel/home
- /panel/users/2
- etc

to `/Areas/Panel/{controller}/{action}`

My current MVC route is:

```
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "area",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

but it isn't working, probably because I don't fully understand how tell the router to use `Website` area as default. I tried various directives right before the controller itself but it did not work.

Could I ask for your advice?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One reason it doesn't work because you have the routes registered in the wrong order. The routes are evaluated from the top to the bottom of the route table and the first match wins.

Another issue is that you need to make the "default" route into an area route (using the `MapAreaRoute` extension method) if you want it to direct requests to the `Website` area.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "area",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapAreaRoute(
        name: "default",
        areaName: "Website",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Reference: [Why map special routes first before common routes in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661062/why-map-special-routes-first-before-common-routes-in-asp-net-mvc/35674633#35674633)

Comment: Hello, no luck unfortunately. I tried the other way around. It works when I go to: `/Website/Home` then I receive an error: `InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml` which makes sense as the desired view is not directly in the project but in Website/Views. I was thinking about something like `template: "Areas/Website/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")` but this isn't working either.

Comment: Thank you. I think the right point is regarding areaName because that's what seems missing to me but unfortunately I am getting an error: `Error CS1739 The best overload for 'MapRoute' does not have a parameter named 'areaName'`. So it seems the issue is how to point to the right area for the `default` declaration...

Comment: Change `MapRoute` to `MapAreaRoute` (see my answer).