# How to set the default area in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, attributerouting, asp.net-core-routing

I am using areas in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 application (MVC).

Now I want all requests without an explicit area to go to the "Main" area by default. This is how I currently set up my endpoint routing:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // 1
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "area",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    // 2
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                       name: "default",
                       areaName: "Main",
                       pattern: "{area=Main}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

**My goal is:**

If the request URL contains an existing area name, use routing [1]. If there is no area name, use routing [2] (which defaults to the "Main" area).

**My problem:**

- Requests to "/main/admin" are working fine.
- Requests to "/admin" result in a 404.

How do I set up the default area?

OK, solved. In the end, this here has been working for me:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "default",
               pattern: "area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


     endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                areaName: "Main",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
 });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

1. If you do not specify the area name, it'll find the  `Controller` and `Action` outside the Areas. Besides,
   The **Important Area** should be outside `Areas` to make it as normal (Default Area) as you wish.

[image]

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {

        // 1
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "area",
            pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        // 2
        endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                           name: "default",
                           pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    });
```

2. Remove redundant `{area=Main}/` in your pattern

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "area",
      template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

   routes.MapAreaControllerRoute(
      name: "default",
      areaName: "Main",
      template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   });
```

Refer the following thread to have a better understanding

[ASP.NET Core 2 default route having areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368557/asp-net-core-2-default-route-having-areas)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Phong. Your lower snippet does not compile. And the upper leads to a 404 still. I thought, I need to start with the most specific route and the proceed with more general routes. In your snippets, I feel like you doing the opposite, no?

Comment: How do you specify the routing to get `Controller` and `Action` outside `Area`. That's my point. https://ibb.co/hcF1XMn

Comment: Hm. Well I have no controller outside from areas. So everything I have is wrapped in areas.However, there is one area that is more important than all my other areas. And my goal is to route to this important area if there is no area in url.

Comment: Obviously, the **Important Area** should be outside to make it as normal (Default Area).

Comment: Haha, yes. But I don't want to change everything now. Thanks Phong. Still looking for a way to make it work my way.

Comment: Did you try this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368557/asp-net-core-2-default-route-having-areas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208969/discussion-between-phong-and-ingmar).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below routing configuration:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "Main",
        areaName: "Main",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

});
```

Comment: Thanks @Xing Zou, but this didn't do the trick. Requests to "/admin" still result in a 404.