# Submitting a form in ASP.NET Core 2 and getting an error "Sending Data Status Code: 404; Not Found"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, form-submit, asp.net-core-2.0

I've tried submit a simple `Form` but I got this error:

> "Sending Data Status Code: 404; Not Found"

I've used `ASP.NET Core 2` and I'm new in it!

How can I solve this problem?

a part of Startup class:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ForTest",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{des}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Comment", action = "Test", des = "no comment!" }
            );
```

a part of cshtml file:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Comment" asp-action="Test"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea id="des" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

a part of CommentController class:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class CommentController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public CommentController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Test/{des}")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Test(string des)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is that error coming from exactly? It's not a standard framework message.

Comment: Your `ForTest` route looks suspicious. If you still have your `Default` route in the project, [your routing is misconfigured](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674633/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using **`asp-for`** attribute on **`textarea`** and use ViewModel class.
Also, fix `Route` attributes.

*Controller / Model*

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string des { get; set; }
}

public class CommentController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Test(TestViewModel testViewModel)
    {
        return Ok(testViewModel.des);
    }
}
```

*cshtml*

```
@using @*Set proper namespace for TestViewModel*@
@model TestViewModel

<form method="post" asp-controller="Comment" asp-action="Test" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea asp-for="des" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[image]