# MVC route is not using default action

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

In my web api, I have created this controller:

```
public class DistributionGroupController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ServiceResult Index(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return null;
        else
            return new ServiceResult();
    }
}
```

In addition, this is my route config. I am specifying my default action for my distribution groups route to be "Index":

```
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "Api action",
        "Api/{controller}/{action}"
    );
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "Api get",
        "Api/{controller}"
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    /*This is the route in question*/
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "DistGroupRoute",
        "api/distributiongroup/{id}/{action}",
        new { controller = "DistributionGroup", action = "Index" }
    );
```

And in my view, I am using this script to (try to) hit my controller:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/distributiongroup/4567bn57n5754",
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

But my ajax call recieves a `404 Not Found` error. However, if I append `index` to my url from my ajax call, my controller is hit. So, in essence, this does **not** work:

```
        api/distributiongroup/4567bn57n5754
```

But this **does** work:

```
        api/distributiongroup/4567bn57n5754/index
```

It's my understanding that my default action should get hit if I don't specify my action in my url. What might I be missing here? And, more importantly, how can I make my `Index` controller get hit when I use a url such as this:

```
        api/distributiongroup/4567bn57n5754
```

(without specifying the `Index` action?

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DistGroupRoute",
    "api/distributiongroup/{id}",
    new { controller = "DistributionGroup", action = "Index" }
);
```

instead of:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DistGroupRoute",
    "api/distributiongroup/{id}/{action}",
    new { controller = "DistributionGroup", action = "Index" }
);
```

There is no need to add the **{action}** in the route template because you already added it in the defaults object.

Basically, you said:
Whenever there is an URL that matches this route template (`api/distributiongroup/{id}/{action}`) trigger the `Index` action in the `DistributionGroup` controller and pass the `id` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because of the order I was specifying my routes in my route config. I was specifying them in this order:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "Api action",
            "Api/{controller}/{action}"
        );
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "Api get",
            "Api/{controller}"
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DistGroupRoute",
            "api/distributiongroup/{id}/{action}",
            new { controller = "DistributionGroup", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Is seems that this route (my default route):

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

was overriding my `distributiongroups` route when I did not specify `index` in my url. I'm still not entirely sure why this happened. But re-ordering my route configs fixed it. I just needed to put my `distributiongroup` route before my default route:

```
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DistGroupRoute",
            "api/distributiongroup/{id}/{action}",
            new { controller = "DistributionGroup", action = "Index" }
        );
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "Api action",
            "Api/{controller}/{action}"
        );
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "Api get",
            "Api/{controller}"
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: See [Why map special routes first before common routes in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661062/why-map-special-routes-first-before-common-routes-in-asp-net-mvc/35674633#35674633)

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.