# ASP.Net MVC: Need guide line for a specific routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

My routing code is not working.

i am showing data in tabular format with sorting and pagination. my solution is working. when i hover mouse on column then url looks like `http://localhost:55831/Customers?page=2&SortColumn=CompanyName&CurrentSort=ContactName`

when i click on pagination numeric link then url looks like `http://localhost:55831/Customers?page=3&SortColumn=ContactName`

i want my url should look like
1) http://localhost:55831/Customers/2/CompanyName/ContactName
2) http://localhost:55831/Customers/3/ContactName

so i add one routing code. here it is

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: null,
        url: "Customers/{page}/{SortColumn}/{CurrentSort}",
        defaults: new
        {
            action = "Index",
            page = UrlParameter.Optional,
            SortColumn = UrlParameter.Optional,
            CurrentSort = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );
```

after adding the above routing code url looks bit weird. now url looks like

```
http://localhost:55831/Customers/1/CompanyName/CompanyName?controller=Customers
http://localhost:55831/Customers/2/CompanyName?controller=Customers
```

so when i click on above links then i am not redirecting to proper controller and action rather getting error.

so it means there is some problem in code which i added as routing in route.config.cs file.

so please help me to get my desired url what i mention above. thanks

### EDIT

my full routing code

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: null,
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{SortColumn}/{CurrentSort}",
        defaults: new
        {
            action = "Index",
            page = UrlParameter.Optional,
            SortColumn = UrlParameter.Optional,
            CurrentSort = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: null,
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{id}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
            page = UrlParameter.Optional,
        }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: Only the last parameter ca be marked `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes i did it what you said but still url looks like http://localhost:55831/Customers/2/CompanyName?controller=Customers and this links is not working.

Comment: Try adding `controller = "Customers"` in the defaults

Comment: @StephenMuecke should work. Reason for that is you didn't specify to which controller your route maps to by default and since routes map to controller/action, when url is generated by mvc, it automatically appends current controller to url. Since, there isn't a placeholder for "controller" parameter in target route, it is appended as querystring parameter

Comment: @Talha5389 
I change the routing code again but still not getting friendly url
`
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: null,
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{SortColumn}/{CurrentSort}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    action = "Index",
                    page = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    SortColumn = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    CurrentSort = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
            );
`

Comment: @MonojitSarkar, how are you generating url for route? Try adding name to route, e.g. name: "CustomerSortRoute" and to generate url use `Url.RouteUrl("CustomerSortRoute",new {SortColumn = "CompanyName", page = 1})`. You might also have to add `action` and `controller` in routeValues while generating, if they aren't in defaults already

Comment: you mean to say i am getting error because i have not mention name for routing? url is generating by  `@Html.ActionLink and PagedListPager`

Comment: @MonojitSarkar, 1st route definition match anything with 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 segments, and your 2nd and 3rd routes are pointless since they can never be reached (the first match wins). But your edit is confusing since its states _my full routing code_, yet it does not include the route in your first code snippet.

Comment: As many others have pointed out, there are several issues with your routing configuration. Routes need to be *constrained* in some way to keep them from overriding other valid route paths. See [Why map special routes first before common routes in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674633/) for an explanation and examples.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work because your routes have optional parameters which conflict with other routes.

For example take the url `/MyController/MyAction/MyPage/213`.

How would the routing be able to determine if you want: `{controller}/{action}/{page}/{id}` or `{controller}/{action}/{page}/{SortColumn}/{CurrentSort}`.

One solution might be to remove the optional parameters:

```
page = UrlParameter.Optional,
SortColumn = UrlParameter.Optional,
CurrentSort = UrlParameter.Optional
```

So your routes would look more like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PageWithSort",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{SortColumn}/{CurrentSort}",
    defaults: new { action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PageWithId",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

However, here you are still going to get a conflict with `PageWithId` and the `Default` routes. So if you never use `id` in the Default routing then you might want to remove the optional parameter there. Or, if all routes with `page` always have an `id` then you could remove the optional parameter there. Alternatively, if `page` and `id` are truely optional you may consider removing the default route as `PageWithId` with the two optionals would handle both.

Side note: You should always name your routes as later it will allow you to do things like this:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Link Text", "RouteName", new { controller = "xxx" })
```

From your provided code you might consider changing

```
@Html.ActionLink("Company", "Index", new { page = ViewBag.CurrentPage, SortColumn = "CompanyName", CurrentSort = ViewBag.CurrentSort })
```

To

```
@Html.RouteLink("Company", "PageWithSort", new { controller = "Customers", action = "Index", page = ViewBag.CurrentPage, SortColumn = "CompanyName", CurrentSort = ViewBag.CurrentSort })
```

Comment: i have add your routing code but still url not become very friendly of links. so here is test project link https://github.com/karlosRivera/ASP.NET-MVC-EF-Sorting-Searching-and-Paging  can you please run and test the code. it is test project and database is there in app_data folder. project size is very small. looking for your further help.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar I have added an example for the route link at the very end of my answer.

Comment: i can change `@Html.ActionLink to @Html.RouteLink` but i have used Pagelist for pagination which generate links where i have no control there to change their ActionLink to routeLink. so tell me what i can do?