# Clicking on routelink url not passing all the data to action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, routelink

I have creating URL using `RouteLink`.

```
@Html.RouteLink("Edit", "PageWithId",
new
{
    controller = "Customers",
    action = "Edit",
    id = item.CustomerID,
    page = ViewBag.CurrentPage
})
```

I am using this routing **PageWithId** with route link

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PageWithId",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Edit", page = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I have 3 routing code. Here is all

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PageWithSort",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{SortColumn}/{CurrentSort}",
    defaults: new { action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional, SortColumn = UrlParameter.Optional, CurrentSort = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PageWithId",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Edit", page = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When I run my program the route link generate URL like `http://localhost:55831/Customers/Edit/1/ALFKI`

When I click on the link the Edit action is getting called but customer id is getting `null` where as **ALFKI** is there in URL as customer id.

Here is my edit action details

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id, int page)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
    if (customer == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;
    return View(customer);
}
```

Please tell me why id is getting null when **ALFKI** as passing as customer id?

Comment: What version of .net are you using?

Comment: Do `SortColumn` or `CurrentSort` have a value (I am suspecting that the wrong route is applied)?

Answer (score 1):

A placeholder (such as `{page}` or `{controller}`) acts like a variable. It can match *anything* and store it in a route value with that same name.

So, what you are actually saying with your configuration is:

**Try**

```
/<anything (optional)>/<anything (optional)>/<anything (optional)>/<anything (optional)>/<anything (optional)>
```

**If that doesn't work, try**

```
/<anything (optional)>/<anything (optional)>/<anything (optional)>/<anything (optional)>
```

**If that doesn't work, try**

```
/<anything (optional)>/<anything (optional)>/<anything (optional)>
```

**If that doesn't work, since {id} is optional try**

```
/<anything (optional)>/<anything (optional)>
```

**If that doesn't work, since {action} is optional try**

```
/<anything (optional)> (if it matches, action will be "Index")
```

**If that doesn't work, since {controller} is optional try**

```
/ (if it matches, controller will be "Home" and action will be "Index")
```

See the problem? The first route can (and will) match a URL of any value and any length from 0 to 5 segments. Once it matches, there is no way to try another route that follows it.

You need to constrain the routes in some way to ensure some URLs can pass through to the next route to try, namely in the cases where you don't want to match that URL.

Also, segments can be made *optional*, but they *cannot change position*. If you pass a value that means `CurrentSort`, that automatically means that all of the parameters to the left of it are *required*.

To me it seems illogical to make `{page}`, `{SortColumn}` and `{CurrentSort}` optional. If you don't need them then either use a different route or take them out of the path altogether and use a query string instead (routes are unaffected by query string values, they only match on the path).

To make the values required, remove the `value = UrlParameter.Optional` from the defaults. In fact, you can just remove all of the defaults because controller and action are already passed in the URL.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PageWithSort",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{SortColumn}/{CurrentSort}"
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PageWithId",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{id}"
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Although these routes can still match *anything*, this will constrain them to a *specific length* and since all 3 of them have a different number of segments they won't conflict. But since they are still so broad, you should think about using [another technique to constrain them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674633) such as literal segments or route constraints. For example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CustomerEditWithId",
    url: "Customers/Edit/{page}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Edit" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first route `PageWithSort` is applied instead of the second one.

Note that the routing framework does not know which parameter name you used to generate the URL. It just looks at the received string `Customers/Edit/1/ALFKI`.

For this string, the first route "PageWithSort" matches with

- controller = Customers
- action = Edit
- page = 1
- SortColumn = ALFKI
- CurrentSort = null (this is OK because it is optional)

Because the first matching route will be used, this URL will never hit the "PageWithId" route.

Maybe you can make the `SortColumn` and `CurrentSort` parameters of "PageWithSort" required?

Or change the order in which the routes are defined.

Or add something unique to the "PageWithSort" route, e.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "PageWithId",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/ID/{id}",
        //                                 ^^
        defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Edit", page = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Adding `/ID` as hard coded part of the URL will make it distinguishable from the other routes (assuming there is not SortColumn calling "ID").