# Configuring URL Routes in an asp.net hybrid (web forms and mvc) app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an app that others have worked on that was originally a Web.forms app with multiple parts and is being converted to MVC. There are two parts that have gone to MVC and one works fine but the other I am having routing issues.

The route appears in .cshtml as:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("TableDetails", new { id=testTable.theId })@Request.Url.Query">Test Table</a>
```

The project is web forms with a folder called Areas > TableProject > Controllers and other folders related to the mvc project. In controllers is a HomeController.cs that has:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id:int}/{seId:int?}", Name = "TableDetails")]
public ActionResult TableDetails(int id, int? seId)
{
    // code
}
```

The route file is as such:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
        routes.IgnoreRoute("anotherproject/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "WebFormDefault",
            string.Empty,
            "~/index.aspx");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "MvcDefault",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
```

I cannot get the table project to work as the TableDetails route cannot be found.  The other MVC project works fine.

The error is:

> A route named 'TableDetails' could not be found in the route collection. Parameter name: name

Comment: Error is: A route named 'TableDetails' could not be found in the route collection.
Parameter name: name

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the method call to register attribute routing, `MapMvcAttributeRoutes`. That means that none of your `[Route]` attributes are being registered.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
    routes.IgnoreRoute("anotherproject/{*pathInfo}");

    // Register [Route] attributes
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "WebFormDefault",
        string.Empty,
        "~/index.aspx");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

> In addition, the `MvcDefault` route is blocking every call to the `Default` route, making `Default` an unreachable execution path. See [Why map special routes first before common routes in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674633) for details.