# How does RedirectToRoute work and how to pass data in it?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to redirect to a route that is in the RecomController and the action is Index, i have defined the path in my RouteConfig file and have also specified an id parameter that i pass when i call my RedirectToRoute function. For some reason it can't find that path.

I have also created a Route attribute above the RecomController Index action but it still doesn't navigate me to that path. Am i missing something?

RouteConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Recomroute",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Recom", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

RecomController.cs:

```
 [Route("Recom/Index")]
        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
         ............//Functioning
        }
```

Calling the function (IN ANOTHER CONTROLLER):

ProjectController.cs:

```
return RedirectToRoute("Recom/Index/{id}", new {id = projectdto.Id });
```

Comment: Regarding your route order, you should look for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35661062/why-map-special-routes-first-before-common-routes-in-asp-net-mvc.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using wrong route name or path in [`RedirectToRoute()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn479129(v%3Dvs.118)), hence it doesn't work:

```
// this is wrong because first parameter did not match
return RedirectToRoute("Recom/Index/{id}", new {id = projectdto.Id });
```

For two parameters overload, it requires route name (not route path) and route values, as shown in definition below:

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToRoute(string routeName, 
                           RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
```

Hence, you need to provide complete route name and route values defined in `RegisterRoutes` (e.g. `Recomroute`).

```
return RedirectToRoute("Recomroute", new {
    controller = "Recom", 
    action = "Index", 
    id = projectdto.Id
});
```

**Side notes:**

1) You still need to provide `controller`, `action` and `id` parameters in order to match route definition.

2) The `Recomroute` seem defined below default route with same route segments definition which overrides all custom routes beneath it, if you want to evaluate `Recomroute` first move it to the top order and use different path against default route.

Comment: I have tried this approach, but it still doesn't work, the debug mode for some reason steps over the return RedirectToTRoute function.

Comment: @Shad What's wrong to use `RedirectToAction()`. What limitation are you facing with this?

Comment: The provided syntax is correct; however there's something may went wrong before `RedirectToRoute` kicks in. I preferred using `RedirectToAction("Index", "Recom")` here because your custom route path in `Recomroute` exactly duplicating the default one.

Comment: The issue with using RedirectToAction is that it uses System.Web.Mvc which interferes with my [HttpPost] request and shows me an error, plus im also using IHttpActionResult to return other things in my api controller

Comment: Please provide the error message you've got, that sounds like different problem than `RedirectToResult` usage. Is that `ProjectController` contains `[HttpPost]` marked action method which redirects to `/Recom/Index`?

Comment: That's not the issue as the error was 'an unbigious reference between System.Web.Mvc and System.Web.Http for HttpPost' I had fixed it by specifying System.Web.Http.HttpPost, the issue is that you can't use a RedirectToAction in an api controller as it only exists in a normal controller.

Comment: I fixed the reference to `System.Web.Http.RedirectToRoute`, therefore `RedirectAction` cannot be used here because I assumed `ProjectController` is a Web API controller, not MVC one. The `routeValues` here is a plain object which should contain controller name, action name and parameters to access the controller action.