# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Removing controller name from url fails for other controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I followed the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3337448/557419) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337372/asp-net-mvc-removing-controller-name-from-url) but when I apply it I get an error if I try to access views under other controllers.

If I go to `http://mydomain/MyActionUnderHome` it works fine, but if I go to `http://mydomain/SomeOtherController/MyAction` it throws

> "The resource cannot be found."

Shouldn't the Default route take over if the URL doesn't match the route definition above the Default route?
Are there perhaps new ways in MVC 5 to do this?

---

My routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "HomeRoute",
    "{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "AccountRoute",
    "{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: @StephenMuecke Added them :)

Comment: `http://mydomain/SomeOtherController/MyAction` matches the first route definition - it equates to ,`SomeOtherController()` method in `HomeController` (with a parameter `id="MyAction"`). Since `SomeOtherController()` probably does not exist in `HomeController` you get the error. In addition, our second route can never be hit because of the first one is identical

Comment: Check the following link will help
[How to remove the controller name from the url using rout in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650332/how-to-remove-the-controller-name-from-the-url-using-rout-in-mvc/34653793#34653793).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57799273/how-to-remove-controller-name-from-url-in-mvc-project/57799331#57799331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have is conflicting routes that the router can't resolve correctly

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "HomeRoute",
    "{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "AccountRoute",
    "{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When the router looks at the path `/youraction/yourparameter` it will resolve to the first route.

The next part of this is that when you provide two values as your URL (as in your example the default router never gets called because the router interprets your input as `/action/id` rather than `controller/action/id`

If you change your routes to be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "HomeRoute",
    "index/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then you'll get your effect. But your second route can still never be called, as your scheme isn't correct.

Answer (score 3):

Better to use `Route` attribute.

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
  [Route("")]
  public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }
  [Route("MyAccount")]
  public ActionResult Account() { return View(); }

}
```

Then add this line t your `RouteConfig` class before the `routes.MapRoute`

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```