# MVC ActionLink advice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.actionlink

I'm just starting out with .NET, and am building a test application. I currently have the homepage set using a `DefaultController`, and an `Index()` action method. This works as expected, and the homepage is simple www.domain.com.

I have created 2 new pages (Terms and Privacy) under the same `DefaultController`, using `Terms()` and `Privacy()` action methods.

I want to be able to browse to these with the URL as www.domain.com/terms and www.domain.com/privacy.

When i use a `<li>@Html.ActionLink("Terms of Service", "Terms", "Default")</li>` it works, but it takes me to the URL at www.domain.com/Default/privacy.

Should i be creating seperate controllers for each of these pages, or am I using the `@html.ActionLink` helper incorrectly? I have previously used `<li><a href="~/privacy">Privacy Policy</a></li>` but I understand this isn't best practice?

Also, is there a way to force links as lowercase?

**My Controller Code:**

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Terms()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need another controller if you are putting those pages in the `DefaultController` and your helpers look correct for the actionlink

Comment: can you post your controller code?

Comment: Have added controller code above. It's currently all very basic

Comment: so when you hover over your `Terms` link, on the bottom left corner, you see `www.domain.com/Default/Privacy`?

Comment: Correct. And i'd expect to see www.domain.com/Privacy ideally.

Comment: If you want `.../Privacy` and `../Terms`, then you need to create specific routes for them (before the default route) - `routes.MapRoute(  name: "Privacy", url: "Privacy", defaults: new {controller = "Default", action = "Privacy" })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these were in the `HomeController` I don't believe you'd have the same problem. However, I think you can get around this by using the `RouteConfig` file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{Action}/{Id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Default", Action = "Index", Id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Generic",
    url: "{controller}/{Action}/{Id}",
    defaults: new { Action = "Index", Id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it does work for my example above, but then it changes the routing for all other controllers. Is there a way i can map a route JUST for the DefaultController and nothing else?

Comment: @Gavin5511 you can leave the default routing but define this first

Comment: Ok great. any chance you can update your answer to show how i can do this?

Comment: You cannot have `url: "{Action}/{Id}",` - thats just saying any url with 2 segments will go to the `Index()` method of `DefaultController` (the Default route will never be hit)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you want to do is hide the controller name in the url.  If that is the case, your question is answered here:

[ASP.NET MVC - Removing controller name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337372/asp-net-mvc-removing-controller-name-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attribute routing to give specific routes to endpoints.

```
[Route("terms")]
public ActionResult Terms()
{
    return View();
}
[Route("privacy")]
public ActionResult Privacy()
{
    return View();
}
```

In your `RouteConfig.cs` you must enable attribute routing with the following line of code: `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`

Now any urls generated with `@Url.Action()` or `@Html.ActionLink` should generate URLS as domain.com/privacy and domain.com/terms