# asp.net MVC - shorten route, disable old route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-routing

I have an asp.net MVC 5 site.

I have many routes - eg

```
http://example.com/places/placename
http://example.com/home/about
http://example.com/home/privacy
```

The first is dynamic - the latter two just point to the about & privacy actions in the home controller.

This works fine, however, I would like all '/home/' URLs to point to the root. eg

```
http://example.com/home/privacy
```

Should point to

```
http://example.com/privacy
```

I would also like the old route to no longer work (duplication of content is bad for SEO).

The former is easy enough to do but the old route still works. What is an elegant way to handle this?

thx.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337372/asp-net-mvc-removing-controller-name-from-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Attribute routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) and decorate those action methods with the pattern you want.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   [Route("privacy")]
   public ActionResult Privacy()
   {
      return view();
   }
   [Route("about")]
   public ActionResult About()
   {
      return view();
   }
}
```

In order to use Attribute Routing it must be enabled by calling `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` in your RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Another option is to specify a route definition **before registering the default route definition**(the order matters.So specific route definition should be registered before the catch-rest default route definition) in your RouteConfig (Traditional routing approach)

So add a specific route definition in your `RegisterRoutes` method in `RouteConfig.cs`

```
//register route for about
routes.MapRoute( "about", "about",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "about" });

routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

With the traditional routing approach, your old `(youtSite/home/about`) and new route pattern (`yourSite/about`) will work. If you want only `yourSite/about`, I suggest you go the Attribute routing approach.

Comment: Thanks - how would you do this in routeconfig.cs - and prevent home/about falling through for the /home/ version of the route as well?

Answer (score 1):

you can use attribute routing of MVC5. To enable Attribute Routing, write below line in **RouteConfig.cs**

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); // Add this line
```

and then your Homecontroller's Action method like this

```
[Route("privacy")]
public ActionResult Privacy()
{
   return view();
}
```

to know more about MVC5 [Attribute Routing](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjArN7Ys8vPAhULrI8KHV-EDq0QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lateshtclick.com%2Fblogpost%2Fattribute-routing-in-aspnet-mvc&usg=AFQjCNHhIlND5kY9vYLiUM8WD4XFFRrEeQ&sig2=DTCqS72n_Kjjo2Ma-C0vog&bvm=bv.135258522,d.c2I)