# Routing in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have two controller based on user type in my ASP.NET Core project. One is `AdminController` for admin and one is `UserController` for users. And there is also `HomeController` for signin and contact page. I am using following map route configuration for both admin and user controllers.

```
config.MapRoute(
      name: "UserRoute",
      template: "{controller}/{username}/{action}",
      defaults: new { controller = "User|Admin", action = "Dashboard" }
);
```

By using above route config I am getting following types of Urls

```
/User/user1
/Admin/user2
```

I don't want the `Admin` and `User` part in URL instead I want

```
/user1
/user2
```

How to remove `User` and `Admin` part from the URL? If I remove controller from `{controller}/{username}/{action}` and specify only controller in defaults then it only works for one controller.

Comment: Check this similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337372/asp-net-mvc-removing-controller-name-from-url. You may utilize route constraint on additional `MapRoute` without affecting default route.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the same URL template with 2 default controllers, because mvc will not understand which controller to use.

You can either have 2 routes and each one with /Admin and /User, just like this:

```
config.MapRoute(
      name: "UserRoute",
      template: "User/{username}/{action}",
      defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Dashboard" }
);

config.MapRoute(
      name: "AdminRoute",
      template: "Admin/{username}/{action}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Dashboard" }
);
```

And from the Home controller, you can check the user role and redirect him to the correct route.

Another approach, would be only one route as you need

```
config.MapRoute(
      name: "UserRoute",
      template: "{username}/{action}",
      defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Dashboard" }
);
```

But in this version, you will have only one controller and you can enable or disable actions according to the user role

Comment: When I use `RedirectToAction(actionname, controllername)`, am I not telling MVC which controller to use? Because I am specifying the controller while redirecting to page. I separated both `admin` and `user `in different controller because both of them have very few similar functionality and if I create only one `UserController` and maintain all types of user in that controller then it will be difficult to maintain.

Comment: In the `RedirectToAction` you tell MVC which controller to use as it is a parameter and by the time the user is logged in, you will already know which controller to use, Admin to User.
Any way, I see most of the sites have different URL for both User and Admin, and in MVC, I usually create an area for admin stuff and even maybe a separate master page.

Comment: I have different master pages for both `user` and `admin` in their respective view folders. I wanted to remove role from url because any one can know type of user just by examining the url. I guess I'll have to create only one `UserController` and handle user types in there but keeping different views and master page for all user types.

Comment: You can remove the user /User from the user role and keep the /Admin only for the admin role since no one will see this role but the admin, this is what i normally do in any web application I develop