# How to remove Home from HomeController in Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have a HomeController and it has many Actions in it. I would like users to visit my actions without typing Home. Here is the Route below

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I would like users not to enter controller name, which is Home in this case. How can I do that? Or is it mandatory?

Comment: You would need to create a specific route for each action in the controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Removing controller name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337372/asp-net-mvc-removing-controller-name-from-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 01** (attribute routing)

Add below line on the top of the other routes in RouteConfig

```
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Then add an attribute route on top of each action as you want. (actions in the home controller in this case)
eg. Below code sample will remove "/Home" from http://site/Home/About and be available on http://site/About

```
[Route("About")] 
public ActionResult About()
{
```

**Solution 02**  (using a Route constraint)  [ [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777525/3128521) ]

Add a new route mapping to RouteConfig as below. (Remember to add these specific routes before the default (generic) routes.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Root",
    "{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { isMethodInHomeController = new RootRouteConstraint<HomeController>() }
);
```

This will remove "Home" from all the actions (routes) of the Home controller
RootRouteConstraint class

```
public class RootRouteConstraint<T> : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var rootMethodNames = typeof(T).GetMethods().Select(x => x.Name.ToLower());
        return rootMethodNames.Contains(values["action"].ToString().ToLower());
    }
}
```

**Optional Info**: This line (constraint) will make sure to apply this routing only for the HomeController

```
new { isMethodInHomeController = new RootRouteConstraint<HomeController>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add custom route before  defult route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "OnlyAction",
        "{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } 
    );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```