# How to remove HOME from the url for action results other than Index

Tags: model-view-controller, routes

How can I replicate this default MVC route code below but to work with multiple ActionResults that are in the home controller. I want them to work just like Index where you do not need /Home/Index in the url to hit example.com/index

```
 routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            
            );
```

I would like to hit example.com/about  and example.com/contact  without needing the the controller name in the beginning.

I have tried adding that same code but replaced Index with another action method and it works but it doesn't allow you to have more than 1 existing in this structure at the same time.
Solution?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I think I got it to work after reading this thread:
[ASP.NET MVC - Removing controller name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337372/asp-net-mvc-removing-controller-name-from-url)

In the RouteConfig I added the following right before the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Root",
    "{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { isMethodInHomeController = new RootRouteConstraint<HomeController>() }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then inside of the Controller whos name you are trying to remove from the URL you need to add this:

```
    public class RootRouteConstraint<T> : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var rootMethodNames = typeof(T).GetMethods().Select(x => x.Name.ToLower());
        return rootMethodNames.Contains(values["action"].ToString().ToLower());
    }
}
```

Now if I go to `example.com/about` , it works and I don't have to use `example.com/Home/About`